# cant make video crop fit in the videoview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view, android-videoview

cannot make a video to crop fit to the screen width, since the video is wide cannot fit in the portrait screen, please let me know how to crop it to stretch to screen width  .

```
  <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/video_intro"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
```

**java code**

```
        vd=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_intro);
        String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.intro;
        vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
        vd.start();
```